# Keyboard sporadically assumes alt key held down

Tags: keyboard

Currently running ubuntu 15.04, and every couple of hours my computer decides that the left alt is held down. it only does this if a keyboard is plugged in, though it does it regardless of which keyboard I have plugged in. I'm dual booting win 8 and ubuntu, and the win 8 partition hasn't had this problem. Shutting down the computer usually fixes the problem, but just restarting doesn't affect it. Any assistance very welcome!

Comment: If it _was_ Windows I'd suggest you were hitting some key combo that switches the keyboard layout to US-International, with the "AltGr" setting. Does such a thing exist on Ubuntu?

Comment: @jdv yes, Super and Space. Are you ever accidentaly hitting that? can you see this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/EXaKU.png

Comment: @Tim I don't know if I've been hitting it previously, but I just tried hitting that combination, and it doesn't start up the problem. Regarding the image- I see the En symbol (no sub 1) and the volume. To the left of "En" is the wifi symbol, then the onscreen keyboard symbol. (Which I'm using to type.)

Comment: @IgneusJotunn okay maybe click the En and add a new layout to see if that fixes it?

Comment: it's quite possible that this is some hardware problem. try booting with a live cd and see if it occurs again